# Resolving value with different behavior, preferably without if else

Tags: java, refactoring

Here is what I'm trying to do

First initiate an optional variable, then do procedure A.
if procedure A yield null then try procedure B and so on.
if all the procedure still yield null, throw exception

```
#pseudocode

Optional<> someVariable;

if (someVariable is empty):
  fetch value through procedure A
  assign to someVariable
if (someVariable is empty):
  fetch value through procedure B
  assign to someVariable
.
.
.
if still empty:
  throw exception
```

The problem is I don't really want to go through procedure B if procedure A already resolve the value and I don't think it is scalable if more procedure is added
any input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With JDK 11 (probably JDK 8+):

```
public class MyClass {

  private Integer procedureA() {
    return ...
  }

  private Integer procedureB() {
    return ...
  }

  ...
  
  private final List<Supplier<Integer>> procedures = List.of(
    this::procedureA,
    this::procedureB,
    // ... as many as you want
  );

  // This code will stay the same, no matter how many procedures you add
  public Optional<Integer> readValue() {
    Integer someValue =  procedures
            .stream()
            .map( Supplier::get )
            .filter( Objects::nonNull )
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow( () -> new RuntimeException( "Exception!" )   );
   // I don't think it makes sense to return an optional in this case
   // but you can do it if you want to
   return Optional.of(someValue);
  }
}
```

This is pretty much the same approach everybody else has suggested, but with the latest Java you can write code that's much more compact and understandable than the one I've seen in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

This has no else

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Integer result = null;
    if ((result = procA()) == null && (result = procB()) == null){
        System.out.println("throw ex");
    }
}

static Integer procA ()  {
    
    System.out.println("procA");
    return null;
}

static Integer procB () {
    System.out.println("procB");
    return null;
}
```

Try changing the values of what the methods return.

Comment: I like the density/brevity of this code.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly verbose but hopefully readable approach:

```
Object someVariable = Stream.of(initialValue)
    .map(obj -> obj == null ? procedureA() : obj)
    .map(obj -> obj == null ? procedureB() : obj)
    .findFirst()
    .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new); // or whatever exception you want
```

Answer (score 1):

If your procedures are relatively simple and can be declared as `Runnable`s. Then we can create a list of Runnables and execute the `run` method with a for loop:

```java
private class ProcedureA implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        someVariable = try fetching value
    }
}

// private class ProcedureB/C/D/E implements Runnable {}

List<Runnable> procedures = List.of(new ProcedureA(), new ProcedureB(), ...);
for (Runnable procedure : procedures) {
    if (someVariable.isPresent()) {
        break;
    }
    procedure.run();
}

if (someVariable.isEmpty()) {
    throw exception;
}
```

If the procedures are somewhat complicated, and will return values or take arguments, then we can use `Callable` or define a custom `Procedure` interface with a running method.

```java
public interface Procedure {
   V running(arg1, arg2);
}

public class ProcedureA implements Procedure {
    @Override
    public V running(arg1, arg2) {}
}

List<Procedure> procedures = List.of(new ProcedureA() ...);
```